# python win32api and selecting tasks configured for Windows 7/2008

Tags: python, winapi

I have recently been working on a script to extract all the scheduled tasks running on a Windows host but I have run into a snag on Win 7 and 2008 hosts as it seems from my investigation that the the win32api taskscheduler class doesn't pick up Tasks where the "Configure For:" does not have Windows XP in the list.

Any thoughts on how to get round this without a complete rewrite?